# Why ref parameters can not be ignored like out parameters?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, ref-parameters

Is there a specific reason why C# 7 bring inlining `out` parameters but not `ref`?

The following is valid on C# 7:

```
int.TryParse("123", out _);
```

But this is invalid:

```
public void Foo(ref int x) { }

Foo(ref _); // error
```

I don't see a reason why the same logic can't be applied to `ref` parameters.

Comment: Would it be because the semantic is different? With `out` you expect a result, with `ref` you pass in a reference.

Comment: What do you propose the value of the parameter should be on input? `default(T)`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert sure, why not ?

Comment: `ref` means that parameter's value passed can be used in the `Foo` method; however *uninitialized* local variable - `Foo(ref _)` - contains trash.

Comment: @ZizyArcher except, as OP clearly states in his question, it was changed in C# 7. Second sentence :|

Comment: @SelmanGenç: I'm just trying to make your feature request complete before you post it on Github. :-P Honestly, though, I see this as much less useful than the same for `out` -- and that isn't even such a hot feature to begin with. What (realistic) methods take `ref` parameters that you'd want to ignore entirely, and work correctly when you pass "the default" for that particular type?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I come across this while writing unit tests, there is a method I was testing and I only care about one parameter, there were two refs that I don't care. this feature would be useful there :) now thinking about it maybe I should change those refs to out...

Comment: @ZizyArcher Well, his explicitly asking why it is so (works for `out`, not for `ref`). So I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.

Comment: @SelmanGenç Do your methods actually use the values passed in to those `ref` parameters? If not, why are you using `ref`. In 9 years of writing C#, I think I've probably used `ref` once. It's not a very widely used feature, so I question why you have a method that takes two of them.

Comment: I've never seen a method that used `ref` and couldn't be improved by introducing either a class or a tuple to get/return the things it was twiddling, or making it a method of a new class. It's OK for a first approach, I suppose, but it becomes tedious quickly enough that you bite the bullet and improve the signature. But that's a subjective discussion more appropriate for the feature request itself, I suppose. And by extension, this isn't such a good question for SO.

Comment: @JLRishe looks like I read the value of one parameter but the other one is only used to set a value. so I will change that one to out.

Comment: @jeroen-mostert the same can be said for `out` parameters. These features exactly allow one not to have to mess with tuples, classes and extra methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is simple: because you're not allowed to pass an uninitialized variable into a `ref` parameter. This has always been the case, and the new syntactical sugar in C#7 doesn't change that.

Observe:

```
int i;
MyOutParameterMethod(out i);  // allowed

int j;
MyRefParameterMethod(ref j);  // compile error
```

The new feature in C#7 allows you to create a variable in the process of calling a method with an `out` parameter. It doesn't change the rules about uninitialized variables. The purpose of a `ref` parameter is to allow passing an already-initialized value into a method and (optionally) allow the original variable to be changed. The compiler semantics inside the method body treat `ref` parameters as initialized variables and `out` parameters as uninitialized variables. And it remains that way in C#7.

Comment: While accurate, this is missing the point. Initializing to default would've been perfectly reasonable. Consider `Thingie MakeThingie ( ref string locationWhereToPutThingie )` that uses predefined location unless provided. Thingies don't care enough about their location for it to be made a part of them, callers sometimes may not care about location either. `MakeThingie ( ref _ )` seems easy enough.